# UNION but keep the first table sort order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have 2 tables

```
EmpID | ProcessID | ID
2     | B         |  1
1     | A         |  2
3     | C         |  3

EmpID | ProcessID | ID
1     | F         |  1
2     | E         |  2
```

I want to UNION these 2 tables and want the final result to be

```
EmpID | ProcessID
2     | B
2     | E
1     | A
1     | F
3     | C
```

Notice that my first table EmpID order is 2, 1, 3 which is based on ID (Identity) column. So what I want is that the final result after UNION is also 2, 1, 3 (ordered by first table ID). If I use UNION and sort by EmpID I will get this instead

```
EmpID | ProcessID
1     | A
1     | F
2     | B
2     | E
3     | C
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Describe how to order, not the order.

Comment: and post the SQL you already wrote, please

Comment: @jarlh: based on my case above, my first table EmpID order is 2, 1, 3. Hence I also want the final union result in 2, 1, 3.

Comment: Use a case expression in the order by.

Comment: @jarlh: can you provide example?

Comment: You must `order by` something. Without that there is on guarantee of order

Comment: Tables have no inherent order. By what *logic*, using just values from columns in table 1, can we define the order?

Comment: **[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=87d3b8cfbe407bfd4a4abf2008242206)** You need to have column to sort, so I added Identity. Without it you can't get stable sort.

Comment: >>>So what I want is that the final result after UNION is also 2, 1, 3.<<< but in your final result the rows from the first and 2nd table are mixed up, it's not  first table + second table order, but a mix

Comment: How do you get the result to be 2, 1, 3 to begin with? Just because it is stored like that in the table doesn't mean it will always be returned that way. If you can sort it somehow, then the solution will be to use a row_number() on each dataset.

Comment: @lad2025: hi, can you check my updated question, so basically your solution is close to what I want, but in my case, the ID in the 2nd table is different compared to first table.

Comment: @warheat1990 that is because the data is not always returned in the same order that it is stored in the table. You need a logic to tell in which order to return the data.
9 out of 10 times it might be returned as 2,1,3 - but it is not a certainty - 1 out of 10 times it might be returned 3,2,1 or 3,1,2 or something else.

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear enough, please check my updated question.

Comment: Then you need to use row_number() on that column - or just sort by that column

Answer (score 1):

Below query can be used to achieve the desired result.

```
select * from(
select empid,process_id,id from emp1
union all
select empid,process_id,id from emp2) emp
order by empid,process_id asc
```

Below is the sqlfiddle link on which your problem was reproduced. Have a look and let me know in case of any issues.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a6a60/10

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t1 table (EmpID int, ProcessID varchar(10), ID int);
insert into @t1 values
(2     ,' B'         ,  1),
(1     , 'A'         ,  2),
(3     , 'C'         ,  3);

declare @t2 table (EmpID int, ProcessID varchar(10), ID int);
insert into @t2 values
(1     , 'F'         ,  1),
(2     , 'E'         ,  2);

with cte2 as
(
select  t2.EmpID, t2.ProcessID, t1.ID, 2 as nr
from @t1 t1 join @t2 t2
        on t1.EmpID = t2.EmpID
),

cte1 as
(
select  *, 1 as nr
from @t1
)

select EmpID, ProcessID
from
    (
    select *
    from cte1
    union all
    select *
    from cte2
    )t
order by id, nr;
```

Comment: Got the same solution, but later than you :) thumb up!

Comment: @Ruslan K.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ROW_NUMBER on both tables, thereafter sort it on ROW_NUMBER basis.

e.g.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 5)), * from Table1
union 
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 5)), * from Table2
```

Note: In place of SELECT 5, you can use anything like SELECT 1, SELECT ‘A’, SELECT NULL, etc

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (<anything that resolves to a constant>)` is effectively telling the server "all rows are equal, apply row numbers in any order you want to" and so doesn't solve any problem where getting some *deterministic* ordering is part of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you only want the two first columns and eliminate the ID column, but still be able to sort by it:

```
SELECT
    EmpID
   ,ProcessID
FROM
(
    SELECT
       *
    FROM
       #tmp1 AS T
    UNION
    SELECT
       *
    FROM
       #tmp2 AS T
) AS A
ORDER BY
    id ASC
```

**EDIT:** I notice that your ID column is sorted ascending on the first table and descending on the secondary table - if that is always the case, you can go like this:

```
SELECT
    EmpID
   ,ProcessID
FROM
(
    SELECT
       EmpID
      ,ProcessID
      ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id asc) AS rw
    FROM
       #tmp1 AS T
    UNION
    SELECT
       EmpID
      ,ProcessID
      ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id desc) AS rw
    FROM
       #tmp2 AS T
) AS A
ORDER BY
    rw ASC
```

Comment: this won't solve the problem as the result will be 1, 2, 1, 2, 3 because ID in table 1 and table 2 is not the same even though they have same EmpID

Comment: Then you need to do a separate row_number() on each table before unioning them.
See my updated answer.

Comment: Your answer does not consider that `UNION is also 2, 1, 3 (ordered by first table ID)`

Comment: @RuslanK. That doesn't make a difference, because we create the row_numbers on each table based on either asc or desc of his ID column, and then we sort by that column in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
DECLARE @table1 AS TABLE (EmpID int, ProcessID varchar(1), ID int)
INSERT INTO @table1
    VALUES (2, 'B', 1),
            (1, 'A', 2),
            (3, 'C', 3);

DECLARE @table2 AS TABLE (EmpID int, ProcessID varchar(1), ID int)
INSERT INTO @table2
    VALUES (1, 'F', 1),
           (2, 'E', 2);

WITH united AS
(
    SELECT EmpID, ProcessID, ID, 1 AS tableNum
        FROM @table1
    UNION
    SELECT EmpID, ProcessID, (SELECT t1.ID FROM @table1 t1 WHERE t1.EmpID = t2.EmpID) AS ID, 2 AS tableNum
        FROM @table2 t2
)
SELECT EmpId, ProcessID
    FROM united        
    WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY ID, tableNum;
```

Output:

```
EmpID       ProcessID
----------- ---------
2           B
2           E
1           A
1           F
3           C
```